# Accessing txt file from another app that is saved on phone || open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) || Android Studio Java Android 11+

Tags: java, android, file, permissions

so I'm quite new to Java/Android Studio etc. I want to access a file that is another app safe in the path "/storage/emulated/0/DataLogger/"

I tried this:
private String get_feature_string(String fileName) {

```
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/storage/emulated/0/DataLogger/"+fileName))) {
        String firstLine = reader.readLine(); // Read the first line

        if (firstLine != null) {
            StringBuilder restOfFile = new StringBuilder();
            String nextLine;
            while ((nextLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                restOfFile.append(nextLine + '\n');
            }
            data = restOfFile.toString();
            return firstLine;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return "";
    }
    return "";
}
```

but it always fails at opening the file:
/storage/emulated/0/DataLogger/23.09.01_15.20.27_raw.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Also I'm completly unsure if this approach is remotely close to how it works as well as which permissions I need. There seem to be a lot of changes happening to file permissions and after several hours of searching I still seem to be hopeless. There seem to be other approaches like ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE, but I really don't understand how to implement them.

I would be glad for any help, thanks :)

Comment: Yes on Android 11+ devices your app can not read files of other apps in the classic way. You should use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to let the user select that file as the .._TREE is for selecting a directory. No permissions needed.